# Where are image files for GNOME Boxes stored?

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, gnome-boxes

Ubuntu 18.04
Gnome Boxes 3.30.3

I have installed Linux Mint as a guest virtual machine in Gnome Boxes.  It works great. I can't figure out where the image file for that guest virtual machine is stored. I've looked at many other questions on this topic, they all turned out to be wrong in my case.

It's not in any of these directories:

```
/home/user/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images
/home/user/.config/libvirt
/home/user/.config/libvirt/qemu
/home/user/.config/gnome-boxes
/var/lib/libvirt/images
```

I don't know where else to look for it.

Also, I don't know the "format" the name of the image file takes, so I don't know how to search for it using a tool like Catfish.

And yet, since I can successfully run Linux Mint within Gnome Boxes, I know there must be an image file somewhere.

How do I find where this file is located?

Answer (score 8):

I found it. It is located at

```
/home/user/.var/app/org.gnome.Boxes/data/gnome-boxes/images
```

I assume it was put into this odd location because I installed gnome boxes via Flathub. I found it by running this command to look for all files in my home directory that are larger than 1 GB:

```
find ~ -size +1G -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Gnome Boxes via snap, check

```
~/snap/gnome-boxes/common/gnome-boxes/images/
```